# How to generate a random integer array satisfying complex constraints

Tags: random

I want to generate several random arrays `{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}` that satisfy the following complex constraints:

```
(2.3 x1 + 4.1 x2 + 2.2 x3 + 3.5 x4 + 1.8 x5  <= 50) && (0 <= x1 <= 5 && 
   0 <= x2 && 1 <= x3 <= 5 && 1 <= x4 && 0 <= x5 ) && (2 <= x3 + x4 <= 5)
```

How I can do it.

In addition, I want to generate integer points in the region and improve the speed of generating these points

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
constraints = (2.3 x1 + 4.1 x2 + 2.2 x3 + 3.5 x4 + 1.8 x5 <= 
     50) && (0 <= x1 <= 5 && 0 <= x2 && 1 <= x3 <= 5 && 1 <= x4 && 
     0 <= x5) && (2 <= x3 + x4 <= 5);

vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
```

Use `constraints` and `vars` to define an [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html):

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[constraints, Evaluate@vars];
```

Use [`RandomPoint[region, n]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) to draw `n` random points from  `region`:

```
sample = RandomPoint[ir, 3]
```

> {{0.569525,0.655619,1.19525,2.5036,15.6858},{0.666914,5.79318,1.71149,2.1047,7.46705},{3.56459,3.98713,3.0594,1.16909,7.3919}}

Verify that each point satisfies the `constraints`:

```
constraints /. Thread[vars -> #] & /@ sample
```

> {True, True, True}

**Update:** ***"to generate integer points in the region"***

Two approaches:

1. Generate all integer tuples inside the cuboid that contains `ir` and select the ones that satisfy the constraints; then sample from the resulting list of tuples.

```
feasibleQ = Function[Evaluate@vars, Evaluate@constraints];

integertuples = Tuples @ MapThread[Range[Ceiling@#, Floor@#2] &, 
    Transpose @ RegionBounds[ir]];

integerfeasible = Select[Apply[feasibleQ]]@integertuples

Length@integerfeasible
```

> 5319

```
RandomChoice[integerfeasible, 3]
```

> {{4, 1, 1, 1, 12}, {0, 4, 2, 3, 9}, {0, 0, 3, 1, 3}}

```
feasibleQ @@@ %
```

> {True, True, True}

2. `Rationalize` the constraints and use `Solve`:

```
solutions = vars /. Solve[Rationalize@constraints, vars, Integers];

Length@solutions
```

> 5319

```
feasibleQ = Function[Evaluate@vars, Evaluate@constraints];

And @@ (feasibleQ @@@ solutions)
```

> True

```
RandomChoice[solutions, 3]
```

> {{0, 5, 4, 1, 8}, {3, 1, 2, 1, 4}, {2, 0, 1, 2, 1}}

Comment: How to deal with the condition that these points are all integer points and how to improve the speed of generating these points.

Comment: @bmc013 you should update your question with this additional set of questions. In the future it might be better to start with this sort of information/requirement in your original post. While kglr is super cool and will likely update with these additional questions being answered, it is more helpful to future users if you update your question with these requirements.

Comment: Thank you @CATrevillian for the kind words:)

Comment: @bmc013, don't know how to add the integer constraint (adding the domain `Element[vars, Integers]` into the constraints does not work).

Comment: @CATrevillian Thank you for your advice, I have updated the question.

Comment: @kglr dude nice edit! I found a way to use `FindInstance` with your definition of `ImplicitRegion` and posted it as an answer, not sure what way is better, but your answer surely is (& more complete, too, what with a defined `testQ` n what-not) :D

Answer (score 4):

Jumping off of @kglr's answer (pre-edit of the integer method), one can use [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html?q=FindInstance) with `RandomSeeding->Automatic` to accomplish exactly the OP's updated task. I am not sure if you can get more efficient than this, as it takes negligible time on my PC for the production of a list of 10 Integer sets using  `RandomSeeding->Automatic`. I suppose it would depend on your precise use case if this is efficient enough.

```
vars /. FindInstance[vars ∈ ir, vars, Integers, 10, RandomSeeding -> Automatic]
```

> {{1, 4, 1, 1, 9}, {0, 3, 2, 1, 8}, {3, 0, 3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 1, 3, 
>     9}, {5, 0, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 1, 1, 1, 4}, {0, 0, 2, 3, 0}, {5, 3, 2, 3, 
>     0}, {2, 1, 1, 2, 15}, {5, 0, 1, 2, 8}}

Here, I use 10 for the number of produced sets as not defining it, i.e., leaving it as 1, only produces the same solution each time.

```
vars /. FindInstance[vars ∈ ir, vars, Integers, RandomSeeding -> Automatic]
```

> {{0, 0, 1, 1, 0}}

kglr's method is faster:

```
(vars /. FindInstance[vars ∈ ir, vars, Integers, 10, 
 RandomSeeding -> Automatic]) // feasibleQ @@@ # & // AbsoluteTiming

(integertuples = 
Tuples@MapThread[{Ceiling@#, Floor@#2} &, 
  Transpose@RegionBounds[ir]];
feasibleQ = Function[Evaluate@vars, Evaluate@constraints];
integerfeasible = Select[Apply[feasibleQ]]@integertuples;
RandomChoice[integerfeasible, 10]) // feasibleQ @@@ # & // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.350308, {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>     True}}
>   {0.0725979, {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>     True}}

Both methods yield appropriate results, however.

With an updated definition of `integertuples`

```
integertuples = Tuples@MapThread[Range[Ceiling@#, Floor@#2] &, Transpose@RegionBounds[ir]];
```

Timing increases slightly

> {0.215071, {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>     True}}

However, if one is timing these appropriately by not computing `integertuples` again each time upon evaluation, one gets

```
RandomChoice[oldintegerfeasible, 10] // feasibleQ @@@ # & // AbsoluteTiming
RandomChoice[integerfeasible, 10] // feasibleQ @@@ # & // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0000818, {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>     True}}
>   {0.0000852, {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>     True}}

Illustrating comparable timings between versions of kglr's `integertuples` (definition shown above is `oldintegertuples` with `oldintegerfeasible` in comparison to kglr's correction using `Range`, which gives all solutions held within the cuboid.)

Comment: please check the corrected version of `integertuples` in my updated post.

Comment: @kglr if it is the edit using `Range`, I find comparable timings, the whole of the method takes a bit longer, but I realized I was timing inappropriately, and updated with that. Seems like your old method was slightly quicker? Maybe? What is the reasoning behind the corrected version?

Comment: the older (incorrect) version  takes only the _**corners**_ of the bounding cuboid (it contains only 2^5 = 32 tuples)  it ignores the integer tuples _**inside**_ the cuboid.

Comment: I think `FindInstance` doesn't guarantee lack of bias on instances it returns. I would be wary of it for this purpose if there are requirements to randomness of results.

Comment: @kirma agreed. When you only use `1` you always get the same output.

Comment: @CATrevillian That is one thing. Another is that even if you would supply different `RandomSeeding` values to it ad infinitum, nothing really guarantees that the distribution would approach uniform distribution over the region. `RandomPoint` is really designed for that purpose, while `FindInstance`... I'm not quite certain what one should say about it. It's definitely practical for many tasks, but maybe random sampling with it comes with caveats.